# socket.io wait for response in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to receive a json file with `socket.on` after an event emission and use that response in another file. My knowledge of sockets is pretty limited. Here's the code.

**main file:**

```
  const socketclass = require('../public/socket/client');
  await socketclass.emitMsg();
  let val = socketclass.receivedSch;
  console.log(val);
```

Obviously the value of `receivedSch` is undefined.

**client.js**

```
var socketIo = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = socketIo('http://localhost:9096');


exports.emitMsg = async function() {
    socket.emit('getSchema', () => {});
}

socket.on('resJson', (response) => {
    exports.receivedSch = response;
    return response;
});
```

The `resJson` event and the JSON file are received through the `9096` port correctly from another server. I just don't know how to wait to receive the event before `let val = socketclass.receivedSch;`

Simply returning `response` would also work for my research, but I don't know how to return it from within the `socket.on`

Comment: Is the function `emitMsg` bespoke or is it generic?

Comment: `emitMsg` is not a promise so -> `await socketclass.emitMsg();` won't work.  Wrap your `exports.emitMsg` inside a `new Promise()`,..

Comment: @Keith it's an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value), which returns a promise

Comment: @George  Yes, a promise that does nothing,. IOW: a useless promise.  Placing `async` on a function doesn't automatically make a callback function into a promise.

Comment: @Keith I agree its a promise that does nothing, but recommending that they wrap the function is a promise will change nothing. There are no callback functions in this code, but placing `async` on a function will make that function return a promise.

Comment: @George  Yes there is a callback..  That's how socket.io ack works.

Comment: @Keith ohh you're on about in `socket.emit`, I thought you meant on the actual `emitMsg` itself, apologies I misunderstood what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using the express app:

**client.js**

```
module.exports = async(app) => {
    var socketIo = require('socket.io-client');
    var socket = socketIo('http://localhost:9096');

    await socket.emit('getSchema', (data) => {
         //console.log('getSCHEMA');
    });

    await socket.on('resJson', (response) => {
          app.jsonhandler = response;
    });

};
```

And requiring that file before booting the app:

```
var controller = require('./client.js')(app.db.models, app);
controller.write();//method that wil use app.jsonhandler
```

The response from the socket can be accessed everywhere by using `app.jsonhandler`

Answer (score 1):

Your `exports.emitMsg` is not doing what you think it should, the `async` keyword here does absolutely nothing apart from returning a promise that resolves to undefined.

Because your `socket.emit` is a callback function you will want to wrap into a `new Promise`.

So try ->

```
exports.emitMsg = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.emit('getSchema', resolve);
  });
}
```

To make your `ack` actually make sense, you might also want to consume the result like->

```
let val = await socketclass.emitMsg();
```

Comment: @George  It's hard to tell, as the server code is not shown here.  But if you want an `ACK / NAK` type response, using 'on' here is not really the best option.   The OP possibly doesn't realize you can get response from an emit if you use the `ack` callback.

Comment: Neither did I, that's why I removed my comment, but you're too fast :)

Comment: But how can you also pass a custom callback to socket.emit if you are taking up that argument with the resolve function?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to achieve this.

1. Include `const EventEmitter = require('events');` on your file.
2. Create Event Emitter object before `socket.on`

   const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
   socket.on('resJson', (response) => {
   exports.receivedSch = response;
   myEmitter.emit('got_response', response); //emit event (important)
   });
3. Recieve your response using your `myEmitter` object.

   myEmitter.on('got_response', function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
   });

It might help you.